# How to fetch gradients with respect to certain occurrences of variables in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Since tensorflow supports variable reuse, some part of computing graph may occur multiple times in both forward and backward process. So my question is, is it possible to update variables with respect their certain occurrences in the compute graph?

For example, in `X_A->Y_B->Y_A->Y_B`, `Y_B` occurs twice, how to update them respectively? I mean, at first, we take the latter occurrence as constant, and update the previous one, then do opposite.

A more simple example is, say `X_A`, `Y_B`, `Y_A` are all scalar variable, then let `Z = X_A * Y_B * Y_A * Y_B`, here the gradient of `Z` w.r.t both occurrences of `Y_B` is `X_A * Y_B * Y_A`, but actually the gradient of `Z` to `Y_B` is `2*X_A * Y_B * Y_A`. In this example computing gradients respectively may seems unnecessary, but not always are those computation commutative.

In the first example, gradients to the latter occurrence may be computed by calling `tf.stop_gradient` on `X_A->Y_B`. But I could not think of a way to fetch the previous one. Is there a way to do it in tensorflow's python API?

**Edit:**

@Seven provided an example on how to deal with it when reuse a single variable. However often it's a variable scope that is reused, which contains many variables and functions that manage them. As far as I know, their is no way to reuse a variable scope with applying `tf.stop_gradient` to all variables it contains.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding, when you use `A = tf.stop_gradient(A)`, `A` will be considered as a constant. I have an example here, maybe it can help you.

```
import tensorflow as tf

wa = tf.get_variable('a', shape=(), dtype=tf.float32,
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.5))
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=(), dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(7))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
l = tf.stop_gradient(wa*x) * (wa*x+b)
op_gradient = tf.gradients(l, x)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


print sess.run([op_gradient],  feed_dict={x:11})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example! `tf.stop_gradient` does solve some part of this problem, as I mentioned in the last paragraph of my description. However it can only block gradients from until the last but one occurrence of   the reused part, there is no way for it to work in other occurrence case.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Maybe you can compute two functions, one stops gradient of the first occurrence, the second stops the second. I think you want to then average the two gradients to update the weights?

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. Here is the thing, since most time it's the variable scope that is reused, I can't think of a way to stop a variable scope's gradient with protecting it being trainable in next occurrences. Designing two function is feasible, but only when you manage these variable by hand. Besides, I just want to get the gradient wrt certain occurrence, since averaging all gradients sort of get the result of directly fetching gradients (their sum).

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this question. Define a custom getter for the concerning variable scope, which wraps the default getter with `tf.stop_gradient`. This could set all variables returned in this scope as a Tensor contributing no gradients, though sometimes things get complicated because it returns a Tensor instead of a variable, such as when using `tf.nn.batch_norm`.